# Example of a sequence in the closed unit ball of $\ell^1$ which does not have any weakly convergent subsequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I am looking forward to having an example of a sequence in the closed unit ball of $\ell^1$ which does not have any weakly convergent subsequence. I need this to prove that the closed unit ball in $\ell^1$ is not weakly compact and hence in turn it will imply that $\ell^1$ is non-reflexive.

My teacher hinted to take the unit basis elements $(e_n)_{n \geq 1}$ of $\ell^1.$ I know that this sequence does not converge in the weak topology but I can't argue whether it has any subsequence which is weakly convergent. Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you prove that the sequence is not converging weakly? Maybe that argument also applies to every arbitrarily chosen subsequence.

Comment: Upon applying $y = ((-1)^n)_{n \geq 1} \in \ell^{\infty} \simeq (\ell^1)^{\ast}$ on the unit basis vectors $e_n$'s in $\ell^1$ would yield a sequence $((-1)^n)_{n \geq 1}$ which being oscillatory does not converge to anywhere. But you can see @daw that $y$ cannot be applied to disprove that the subsequence $(e_{2n})_{n \geq 1}$ does not converge weakly as it will give rise to the constant sequence $\{1, 1, 1, 1, \cdots \}.$

Comment: If the subsequence is indexed by $n_k$ then test with the sequence $y = \sum_k (-1)^k e_{n_k}$.

Comment: @daw$:$ Hmm got it. In this case $y$ applied to the subsequence $\left ( x_{n_{k}} \right )_{k \geq 1}$ is $(-1)^{k}$ and as $k$ varies it gives rise to an oscillating sequence which cannot converge. So there is no subsequence of $(e_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $\ell^{1}$ which is weakly convergent and hence the closed unit ball in $\ell^{1}$ cannot be weakly compact although it is weak*-compact. Nicely done. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @daw$:$ This actually proves that $\ell^1$ is non-reflexive and since $\ell^1$ is Banach it shows that the Banach spaces $c_0$ and $\ell^{\infty}$ are non-reflexive spaces as well. Interesting indeed!

Comment: Fun fact: A sequence $x_n$ in $X$ is called weakly Cauchy if for every $f \in X^*$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges. Rosenthal's theorem states that a bounded sequence $x_n$ in a Banach space admits no weakly Cauchy subsequences if and only if and only if it admits a subsequence that is (isometrically equivalent to) the Schauder basis of $\ell_1$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos$:$ Hmm nice indeed! Where do I find a proof of this theorem?

Comment: @RKC I think you can find a proof in   "W.T. Gowers, Ramsey methods in Banach spaces, Handbook of the geometry of Banach spaces vol.2, W.B. Johnson and J.Lindenstrauss, eds, Elsevier, Amsterdam (2003)." It uses combinatorial tools from Ramsey theory

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos$:$ I will surely look into it. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @RKC no problem. Alternatively you can Google Rosenthal's $\ell_1$ theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stronger conclusion can be proved. The sequence $e_n$ does not admit any weak accumulation point. Assume by contradiction that $u\in \ell^1$ is such  an accumulation point. There is $n_0$ such that $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty |u_n|<{1\over 2}.$ Let $$v_n=\begin{cases} 0 & n<n_0\\ 1 &n\ge n_0\end{cases}$$ Then the set $$U=\left \{x\in \ell^1\,:\, |v(x)-v(u)|<{1\over 2}\right \}$$ is  open in the weak topology, where  $v(x):=\sum v_nx_n.$ Moreover $u\in U,$ but $e_n\notin U$ for $n\ge n_0.$

Comment: Hmm that's an equally nice argument as well along with daw. I truly appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Could you suggest me some books or articles where I can find exercises with solutions regarding this to work with? Actually my masters is about to end and I am willing to get into PhD by this year. I have a PhD interview in the month of June. Could you suggest me something for this? My area of interest is functional analysis. I have actually a very little or almost no experience about interviews. What kind of questions are generally asked in the interviews if one's area of interest lies in functional analysis?